# How to define several "id"s in one javascript code?

Tags: javascript

The following script written for a progress bar, is assigned to a `div` with `id=container1`. This is while I have several `div`s with ids like container2, container3 and ... which all should be referred to this script.

How can I assign this script to all `div`s?

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container1, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#66cc33',
  trailColor: 'transparent',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
});

bar.animate(1.0); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

Comment: May I know where is the definition for `ProgressBar.Line`??

Comment: look through call and apply in javascript

Comment: The `ProgressBar.Line` code is acting on the division by `id="container1"`, I want it to work on divisions with id: container2, container3 and ... as well.

Comment: @Bálint Division is a real term.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want several progressBar instances referenced to the same options object.

```
var progressBarOptions={
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#66cc33',
  trailColor: 'transparent',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
}

var bar1 = new ProgressBar.Line(container1, progressBarOptions);
var bar2 = new ProgressBar.Line(container2, progressBarOptions);
var bar3 = new ProgressBar.Line(container3, progressBarOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use closures, then each of these containers are accessible from the window object and you can use array access to get the objects:

```
var containerCount = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= containerCount; i++) {
    var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(window["container" + i, {
        // Stuff here
    }
}
```

If you do use closures then you need to put these in an object and use the same thing but replacing the `window` with the object's name.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API of `ProgressBar`. You have to read the API document or the  definition of `ProgressBar.Line` to figure out if `new ProgressBar.Line(option)` could return the same instance each time.